# How to remove salt from salted pumpkin seeds

Tags: food

I bought some shelled pumpkin seeds. I didn't notice that they were salted at the time of buying.

They taste unbearably salty and I want to remove salt from it completely if not to a substantial extent.

I tried soaking a few of them in water overnight but they tasted almost as salty the next day.

Is there are another way to remove the salt from it? I noticed that the salt is coated on the shells.

Is there some DIY osmosis setup that can be made?

Comment: Are these things so expensive that it's worth investing hours of time into a lifehack to remove the salt? Why not just give them to someone who likes them salted and buy some unsalted ones?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there's a crust or a layer of salt on the outside, put them into a cloth (like a clean kitchen towel or a clean pillow case) and rub them for a while. This should remove the salt from the seeds and you can sieve it out.

If there's no visible salt on them, they were probably soaked in salt water and absorbed it. It's basically impossible to remove all the salt from them. The best you could try is soaking them in clean water **and changing the water several times**. I'd say every 30 - 60 minutes at first for several hours. Then let them dry on a baking sheet.

If all that didn't work, consider using them as a cooking ingredient instead of eating them. Compensate for their saltiness by using less salt in the dish.

Answer (score 2):

Notes:

1. depending on how the seeds were salted, it may happen that the salt is already impregnated in the core. In this case, you cannot really remove the salt.
2. I really hope that the seeds still have the shell, and that the salt is on their shell. Otherwise, you are in the case of Note 1 above.

---

You do not have many options to get rid of the extra salt:

- wash the seeds - you already tried and did not work;
- "break" the shells carefully so the salt does not touch the core (too much);
- throw them away (especially if you did not buy supplies for an entire stadium) and buy others not salted + remember for the future to not buy salty seeds.

---

**shelled** is a highly ambiguous word, being able to mean opposite things at the same time:

[image]

Comment: Oh in my case it has the shells present.

Comment: No need to throw them away... you can give them away.

Answer (score 0):

Just wash the pumpkin seeds thorough strainer buy rubbing the seeds against each other then immediately roast (bake) them to golden color 180 C
They will be easier to crack also will be tastier.

Answer (score 0):

I buy pepitas for myself quite often but can't stand all the salt. I take a cup full & put them in a bowl, then I scoop them up in one hand put them back into the bowl & brush off the salt that clings to my palm. I do that at least 20 times & get rid of 75 percent of the salt. It only takes 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I soaked them in boiling water and then rinsed them several times. In boiling water no less then a hour.